# Date picker mouse Pointer Changing from arrow to circle

Tags: javascript

Have an issue with mouse pointer when choosing Dates and Times from calendar input fields.

Mouse pointer changes from arrow to round circle with bar through it.

Using the following calls

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
integrity="sha256-eTyxS0rkjpLEo16uXTS0uVCS4815lc40K2iVpWDvdSY="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js">
```

```
<script src="https://www.website.com/01DatepickerTEST/DateTimeInsert.js"></script>
```

Can view at https://www.carltonparkandfly.com

Many Thanks

B.

Comment: Please give us a [minimal producible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can't really help you with just the library used

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML on the page of the site you provided the `input` elements have the `readonly` attribute. Remove that attribute and the styles that change the `cursor` to `not-allowed` won't apply.

e.g. instead of:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  id="DropOffDate"
  name="DropOffDate"
  size="7"
  maxlength="16"
  style="text-align: center; white-space: pre; width: 90px;"
  readonly
  class="hasDatepicker"
>
```

Change it to the following (removing the `readonly` attribute):

```html
<input
  type="text"
  id="DropOffDate"
  name="DropOffDate"
  size="7"
  maxlength="16"
  style="text-align: center; white-space: pre; width: 90px;"
  class="hasDatepicker"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Tried it, but it eliminates the Datepicker altogether. Have used onfocus ="this.blur()"></p> which works for both Daterpicker fields but not for the Time fields. Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @HawkWeb Does `style="cursor:default;"` help? `<input type="text" id="DropOffDate" name="DropOffDate" size="7" maxlength="16" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre; width: 90px;` **`cursor:default;`** `" readonly class="hasDatepicker">`

Comment: @Novice.  Thanks. Tried that, same result, leaves Datepicker Field Blank.